# How to Combine 3 queries Using Union all Or any New Solution

Tags: php, mysql

**I have 3 Queries Like**

```
SELECT count(*) AS Notificationcount  FROM notifications WHERE email='$email'    and seen='NO' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) AS MessageCount FROM messages WHERE email_to='$email' and seen='NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*)  AS FriendsCount from friends where profileid2='$email' and requeststatus='pending'
```

**I wanted To combine 3 queries Result Into one
How can we do that
Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
(SELECT count(*) AS Notificationcount FROM notifications WHERE email='$email' and seen='NO') as a,
(SELECT count(*) AS MessageCount FROM messages WHERE email_to='$email' and seen='NO') as b,
(SELECT count(*) AS FriendsCount FROM friends where profileid2='$email' and requeststatus='pending') as c
```